# Generating all DAGs with n vertices

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-theory, enumeration

I would like to generate all DAGs with n vertices, *up to isomorphism* - that is, unlabeled DAGs without duplicates. Yes, I know there are a *lot* of these, but I'm mostly concerned with small numbers (e.g., n less than 10) where stuff is still tractable.

Obvious approaches such as adding all possible combinations of edges have two main drawbacks:

1. Such an generates more duplicates (isomorphs) than unique graphs, particularly as `n` grows.
2. Each generated graph needs to be checked to see if it contains cycles.

Comment: See http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29552/enumerate-all-non-isomorphic-graphs-of-a-certain-size

Comment: I have. As far as I know nauty is only effective for undirected graphs. It is possible in theory to generate all undirected graphs, and then all non-isomorphic orientations of such graphs, but this approach fails to be practical given restrictions such as no cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a [simple complete graph Kn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph), where n is the order of the graph and then enumerate all of its [spanning trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree). [The algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#cite_note-23) is a modified DFS in that it uses backtracking and avoids [bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)) (to keep producing connected trees) while it explores all possible different combinations.

According to [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#Counting_spanning_trees), there are `n^(n-2)` (where `^` denotes raising to a power) spanning trees on a Kn, so your worst case scenario probably looks like `9^7=4782969` and includes duplicates.

This is also reminiscent of a "sub-problem" in [Motif Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_motif) where the objective, for [some algorithms](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/mcb/UriAlon/download/network-motif-software) (or [this one](http://theinf1.informatik.uni-jena.de/motifs/)), is to generate [all simple connected **graphs** (not limited to trees) of order n (motifs)](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/mcb/UriAlon/sites/mcb.UriAlon/files/uploads/NetworkMotifsSW/mfinder/motifdictionary.pdf), in order to then produce a decomposition of the graph into those n motifs. So, that literature might be of some use to you as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The main problem is "with duplicates". I wasn't clear enough in my question (I've added clarification now), but the main trick is to avoid the duplicates (i.e., generation of DAGs that are isomorphic) inherent in most naive approaches. Also, your estimate for `n=9` seems to be off - indeed, there are (without duplicates) 20,286,025 unlabeled DAGs for `n=9` - already more than your 4,782,969 (which has duplicates) - see [A003087](https://oeis.org/A003087).

Comment: In fact, it seems that the spanning tree approach cannot work. For example, how do you go from the (undirected) spanning tree to a DAG? Then, how would directing the edges of a spanning tree ever generate the trivial "diamond DAG" where you have `a -> {b, c}, {b, c} -> d`? Such a DAG has a cycle in its undirected skeleton so I don't see how directed the edges of a tree (which has no cycles) could generate it.

Comment: It is not my estimate, all I did was to use Cayley's formula and it counts certain trees twice. But yes, I didn't keep "directed" in mind. You could tag duplicates with a metric  and reject them during discovery but that's just a remedy. For the DAG issue, see Motifs. Many more there because each edge has three states. Can I ask what sort of a problem are you working on?

Comment: Sorry I should have said "derivation", not estimate. I want to generate all possible chains of binary functions, and it seems like getting the restricted class of DAGs with in-degree 2 (and some additional requirements) would satisfy it.

Comment: Can you capture or formulate the problem in a RegEx and then use a "reverse" regex to generate all possible realisations? (For example, see the [rstr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rstr/2.1.3) (specifically, the Xeger part) and [exrex](https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex) python modules)

Comment: Pretty interesting, but I doubt a regex is rich enough to capture concepts like "connected"? Also, it seems likely that the reverse regex approach wouldn't really manage to avoid the tough graph theory issues relating to isomorphism, versus approaches that tackle it head on.

Comment: On the contrary for "connected".A regex is the formula of a [syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and it will therefore always produce connected graphs. So, binary functions like "f(f(x,y),y)" or "f(f(f(f(x,f(x,f(y)))))" could be easily captured by a regex. The challenge is in the formulation of the problem. As for "isomorphism", you are of course right, reverse regex is an exhaustive search but it doesn't recognise and avoid symmetry to reduce duplicates. Can you please add these details with a little bit more info (if possible) to the question?